# Operator space tensor products

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-spaces

Given two Banach algebras  $A$ and $B$ with operator space structure on each of them, i.e both of them are closed subspaces of $B(H_1)$ and $B(H_2)$ respectively for some Hilbert spaces $H_1,H_2$. Does their operator space projective tensor product and Haagerup tensor products form Banach algebra? In other words   is operator space projective/Haagerup tensor norm submultiplicative on $ A\otimes B$?

Comment: The answer is yes for the os-ptp **if** one assumes that the multiplication maps $A \times A \to A$ and $B\times B \to B$ are jointly completely bounded. My instinct is that if you do not make this assumption, then there will be counterexamples, but I cannot think of one immediately

Comment: Any reference for your first statement?

Comment: @OperatorZebra  Look up the notion of a "completely bounded (or quantised) Banach algebra" e.g. in the book of Effros and Ruan.  If $A\times A\rightarrow A$ is jcb then it extends to the os-ptp yielding a completely bounded map $A \widehat\otimes A\rightarrow A$.  Then $(A\widehat\otimes B)\widehat\otimes(A\widehat\otimes B) \cong (A\widehat\otimes A)\widehat\otimes (B\widehat\otimes B) \rightarrow A \widehat\otimes B$ is completely bounded, so $A\widehat\otimes B$ is a (cb) Banach Algebra.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. Any words about Haagerup tensor product?